# Passing data from controller to view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel and I have been trying to store all records of table 'student' to a variable and then pass that variable to a view so that I can display them.

I have a controller - ProfileController and inside that a function:

```
public function showstudents() {
    $students = DB::table('student')->get();
    return View::make("user/regprofile")->with('students',$students);
}
```

In my view, I have this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        //---HTML Head Part
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi {{ Auth::user()->fullname }}
        @foreach ($students as $student)
            {{ $student->name }}
        @endforeach
        @stop
    </body>
</html>
```

I am receiving this error: `Undefined variable: students (View:regprofile.blade.php)`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Can you give this a try,

```
return View::make("user/regprofile", compact('students')); OR
return View::make("user/regprofile")->with(array('students'=>$students));
```

While, you can set multiple variables something like this,

```
$instructors="";
$instituitions="";

$compactData=array('students', 'instructors', 'instituitions');
$data=array('students'=>$students, 'instructors'=>$instructors, 'instituitions'=>$instituitions);

return View::make("user/regprofile", compact($compactData));
return View::make("user/regprofile")->with($data);
```

Comment: Oops I had a missing bracket after compact('students). Thanks

Answer (score 20):

For Passing a single variable to view.

Inside Your controller create a method like:

```
function sleep()
{
        return view('welcome')->with('title','My App');
}
```

In Your route

```
Route::get('/sleep', 'TestController@sleep');
```

In Your View `Welcome.blade.php`. You can echo your variable like `{{ $title }}`

For An Array(multiple values) change,sleep method to :

```
function sleep()
{
        $data = array(
            'title'=>'My App',
            'Description'=>'This is New Application',
            'author'=>'foo'
            );
        return view('welcome')->with($data);
}
```

You can access you variable like `{{ $author }}`.

Comment: Better elaborate answer.

Answer (score 11):

The **best and easy way** to pass single or multiple variables to view from controller is to use **compact()** method.

**For passing single variable to view**,

```
return view("user/regprofile",compact('students'));
```

**For passing multiple variable to view**,

```
return view("user/regprofile",compact('students','teachers','others'));
```

And in view, you can easily loop through the variable,

```
@foreach($students as $student)
   {{$student}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this as well:

```html
public function showstudents(){
   $students = DB::table('student')->get();
   return view("user/regprofile", ['students'=>$students]);
}
```

Also, use this variable in your `view.blade` file to get students name and other    columns:

```
{{$students['name']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
return View::make('user/regprofile', array
    (
        'students' => $students
    )
);
```

Or if you want to pass more variables into view:

```
return View::make('user/regprofile', array
    (
        'students'    =>  $students,
        'variable_1'  =>  $variable_1,
        'variable_2'  =>  $variable_2
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.6:

```
$variable = model_name::find($id);
return view('view')->with ('variable',$variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function showstudents() {
     $students = DB::table('student')->get();
     return (View::make("user/regprofile", compact('student')));
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some comments explaining how your code answers the question in order to improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code :

```
Controller:
-----------------------------
 $fromdate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime(Input::get('fromdate'))); 
        $todate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime(Input::get('todate'))); 

 $datas=array('fromdate'=>"From Date :".date('d-m-Y',strtotime($fromdate)), 'todate'=>"To 
        return view('inventoryreport/inventoryreportview', compact('datas'));

View Page : 
@foreach($datas as $student)
   {{$student}}

@endforeach
[Link here]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$books[] = [
            'title' => 'Mytitle',
            'author' => 'MyAuthor,
            
        ];

//pass data to other view
return view('myView.blade.php')->with('books');
or
return view('myView.blade.php','books');
or
return view('myView.blade.php',compact('books'));

----------------------------------------------------


//to use this on myView.blade.php
<script>
    myVariable = {!! json_encode($books) !!};
    console.log(myVariable);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 8 and above, You can do route binding this way.

```
public function showstudents() {
    $students = DB::table('student')->get();
    return view("user/regprofile",['students'=>$students]);
}
```

In the view file, you can access it like below.

```
@foreach($students as $student)
        {{$student->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is not route-model binding.