# How to pass variable with response view in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to pass variables with response view in Laravel, but it is not allowing me to do so. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
return response(view('home'))->with('name','rocky');
```

the above method doesn't work,

the second one I tried is as follow:

```
return response(view('home'), ['name','rocky']);
```

but I don't know how to use the above one?

**NOTE:** I don't want to use view::make method, I want to pass variable with response method.

Comment: where do you want to send the information?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220482/passing-data-from-controller-to-view-in-laravel/34589202#34589202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is not passed in as a parameter to `response()`, it is called as a method on `response()`. So, you need to change your code to:

```
return response()->view('home', ['name' => 'rocky']);
```

If you don't actually need the full response object (you don't need to modify headers or anything), you can just return the view object using the `view()` helper method:

```
return view('home', ['name' => 'rocky']);
```

You can read more in the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#view-responses):

```
return response()->view('hello', ['name' => 'rocky']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the view method itself. E.g.:

```
$name = 'rocky';
return view('home', compact('name'));
```

My suggestion is you read the Laravel documentation thoroughly, and master the basics of PHP. (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$name = 'rocky';
return view('resizeImage',compact('name'));
```

Basically `reponse()` will help you to customize the response's HTTP status code and headers so no need to use it. See [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#basic-responses)

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that,

```
$name = 'rocky';
return view("folder_name.blade_name", compact("name'));
```

In your case, `blade_name` will be `home` and check if there is any folder above it, inside `resources` folder.

I hope this will work.