# pass array value from controller to view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i am new to larvel.I tried to pass the variable from controller toview but it did not worked.
i am getting an error:

> ### "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

code used in controller:

```
public function showWelcome()
{
return View::make('hello', array('theLocation' => 'NYC'));
}
```

Code in hello.blade.php:

```
<h1 class="highlight">Blade has arrived in {{ $theLocation }} .</h1>
```

can you tell me is there any syntax error in the above code and is there any possibility of debugging the error??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data from controller to view in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220482/passing-data-from-controller-to-view-in-laravel)

Comment: I don't think that's where the problem is. I think you didn't set Laravel up correctly. You'll need to do some debugging. 1.if it's development environment I suggest you edit .env (root of application) and set APP_DEBUG=true for more expressive errors. If it's prod environment I suggest you to trace the error in storage/logs/laravel.log.

Comment: where will i find .env in the root folder of laravel as i have installed in wamp serve @devk k

Comment: @PullataPraveen I don't know how you have your Laravel app set up. But it's in the root directory of the app. As in [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel). When setting up a new project you usually have to copy the .env.example to .env and set up the configuration you need.

Comment: this is the error i am getting **ErrorException in 0d70bc14eead3b1b3264aab0cd33a9878b4a895f.php line 83:
Undefined variable: theLocation (View: D:\wamp64\www\newapp\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)** @devk

Comment: @PullataPraveen well this indicates that the code you posted has nothing to do with the error you're getting :p. You're missing `$theLocation` in your `welcome.blade.php` view and not in your `hello.blade.php` view (which is the one you posted).

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to pass data from Controller to View like:

```
return view('hello')->with(['key' => 'value']);
```

or

```
return view('hello', ['key' => 'value']);
```

And you can use it on view like:

```
<p>{{ $key }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Controller

```
return view('hello')->with(['theLocation' => 'NYC']);
```

View

```
<h1 class="highlight">Blade has arrived in {{ $theLocation }} .</h1>
```