# search query not working in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to return the results of what the user write in the search bar, but when i press search to test it nothing happens.

this is how i created the search bar

```
<form class="form-inline" role="search" action="{{ route('search-source') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchbar" placeholder="Find a source!">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

in my controller i have the following code to find what the user has entered in the search bar. It searches the datebase for a title thats like whats written in the search bar. If nothing is found it return's an error (this is working).
if a row higher than 0 return it need to bring that result back to the page

```
public function searchSource(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'searchbar' => 'required',
    ]);

    $find = $request['searchbar'];

    $query = Source::where('title','LIKE', '%'.$find.'%')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    if(count($query) > 0) {
        return redirect()->route('sources-index')->with(['query' => $query]);
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('sources-index')->with('customerror', 'nothing found, try a different searchterm.');
    }
}
```

back on the page it need to get the result if there is asked for a searchterm,  else it need to give everything of the database

```
@if(!empty($query))
    @foreach($query as $querys)
        <tr>
            <td class="source-cell">
                {{$querys->title}}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{$querys->summary}}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{$querys->course->name}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@else
    @foreach ($sources as $source)
        <tr>
            <td class="source-cell">
                {{$source->title}}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{$source->summary}}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{$source->course->name}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

I tried `dd()` on a couple of places and everything  worked fine, except on the page, i tried `dd($query)` after the if statement nothing happend.

I tried it after the foreach nothing happend.

But when i tried it before the if statement i got an error

> Undefined variable: query (View:
>   ...\resources\views\sources\index.blade.php)

What am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redirect()->with()` uses session to store the data, so you'll need to change the code to:

```
@if (session()->has('query'))
    @foreach(session('query') as $querys)
```

Or, you need to change `redirect()` part to this:

```
return view('query.index', compact('query'));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your above code `$query` is misspelled

Change

```
@if(!empty($uery))
```

to

```
@if(!empty($query))
```

Modify your controller like below :

```
public function searchSource(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'searchbar' => 'required',
    ]);
    $find = $request['searchbar'];
    $query = Source::where('title','LIKE', '%'.$find.'%')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return redirect()->route('sources-index')->with(['query' => $query]);

}
```

Modify your view like below :

```
@if(!empty($uery))
    @foreach($query as $querys)
        <tr>
            <td class="source-cell">
                {{$querys->title}}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{$querys->summary}}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{$querys->course->name}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@else
nothing found, try a different searchterm.
@endif
@if(!empty($sources))
    @foreach ($sources as $source)
        <tr>
            <td class="source-cell">
                {{$source->title}}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{$source->summary}}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{$source->course->name}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@else
nothing found, try a different searchterm.
@endif
```

Because in your else part redirection does not have $query variable.

Comment: This is not a problem OP gets, look at the error message in Peter's question (Undefined variable: query), so it's definitely just a typo.

Comment: And your updated answer will not work too, because redirect is still using session.

Comment: Updated my code return redirect()->route('sources-index')->with('customerror', 'nothing found, try a different searchterm.'); does't have query variable, So this might be issue

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Here not using session in my code, Just passing the values in variable : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220482/passing-data-from-controller-to-view-in-laravel

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin as you mentioned in your commant we can use compact or else will pass the values by using "with" also.

Comment: @Muthu17 no, he uses it since before `redirect()` Laravel stores all the data  you put into `with() `in the session. `redirect()` and `view()` are different methods.

Comment: stil getting the same problem this just got rid of the error message its like its skipping the if statement

Comment: @PeterArents Try to echo your query in controller, I think there is no record for your query thats why its returning to else part. and as your previous condtion also goes to else part only. Thats the reason you got undefined variable error

Comment: Everyone thanks for your help the answer of @alexey mezenin worked so im happy now 

Answer (score 0):

@ Peter Arents Could you please try as below

```
$query = Source::where('title', 'LIKE', "%$find%")->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
```