# laravel 5.4 pass data to create controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have the view /station/{id} that has within it a list of newscasts. I am wanting to create a newscast in the list.

in **station.show.blade:**

```
<td colspan="11">
    @can('newscast_edit')
    <a href="{{ route('newscast.create', [$station->id]) }}"
       class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Add Newscast</a>
    @endcan
</td>
```

in **NewscastsController:**
(before changes)

```
/**
 * Show the form for creating new Newscast.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    if (!Gate::allows('newscast_create')) {
        return abort(401);
    }
    $relations = [
        'for_stations' => \App\Station::get()->pluck('calls', 'id')->prepend('Please select', ''),
    ];
    $backUrl = Session('_previous');
    session(['backUrl' => $backUrl]);

    return view('newscast.create', $relations);
}
```

in **newscast.create.blade:**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                {!! Form::label('for_station_id', 'For Station*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::select('for_station_id', $for_stations, old('for_station_id'), ['class' => 'form-control
                select2']) !!}
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                @if($errors->has('for_station_id'))
                <p class="help-block">
                    {{ $errors->first('for_station_id') }}
                </p>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to remove the `relations` line in **NewscastsController** and pass the station ID to **newscast.create.blade** in place of the `select`, as `for_station_id`

I've tried several ways of going about this including [Passing data from controller to view in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220482/passing-data-from-controller-to-view-in-laravel) and https://laravel.io/forum/07-26-2014-routing-passing-parameters-to-controller  without success.

Modifying the `create` function to `public function create($station_id)`
caused this error:
    `ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 57: Internal error: Failed to retrieve the default value`

I googled that error message as well and didn't come up with any improvement.
I'm sure this is probably showing off how much of a noob I still am at both php and Laravel. What am I missing?

Comment: What do you see if you dump `$for_stations`? Also, what's in your `routes.php` file?

Comment: In web.php (the routes file) `//Newscasts routes
    Route::resource('newscast', 'NewscastsController');
    Route::post('newscasts_mass_destroy', ['uses' => 'NewscastsController@massDestroy', 'as' => 'newscasts.mass_destroy']);`

Comment: I can't access `$for_stations` with the code as it was above. With **station.show.blade** changed to `<a href="{{ route('newscast.create')  }}"` and **NewscastController** as above, there are 26 entries in the `$relations` array passed from the controller, and the same number in the `for_stations` array in **create.blade** -- contents of the two are identical, as they should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make the following changes:

in **NewscastsController**:

```
public function create($id, $calls)
{
    if (! Gate::allows('newscast_create')) {
        return abort(401);
    }

    $backUrl = Session('_previous');
    session(['backUrl' => $backUrl]);
    return view('newscast.create', [ 'station_id' => $id, 'calls' => $calls ]);
}
```

(I ended up passing a second parameter when I got the first one working.)

in **web.php** (router):
`Route::get('newscast/create/{station_id}/{calls}', 'NewscastsController@create')->name('newscast.create');`

in **station.show.blade**:
`<a href="{{ route('newscast.create', [$station->id, $station->calls]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Add Newscast</a>`

in **newscast.create.blade**:

```
<h3 class="page-title">Add Newscast for {{ $calls }}</h3>
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['newscast.store']]) !!}

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                {!! Form::hidden('for_station_id', $station_id, old('for_station_id'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
```

It seems this is essentially what [@EddyTheDove](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4464871/eddythedove) recommended, but either I didn't understand the recommendation correctly or I had something else going on that caused it to error the first time I made those changes. The ultimate solution for me was when I stumbled across the DebugBar package for Laravel 5 (    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.3",) and was able to dig through the whole request.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are modifying the default `create()` function by passing it parameters, you can no longer use it from `Route::resource()`. Therefore, you have to manually define it, above `Route::resource('newscast')`

```
Route::get('newscast/{station_id}', 'NewscastController@create')->name('newscast.create');

//Define your resource routes, excluding 'create'
Route::resource('newscast', 'NewscastsController', ['except' => ['create']);
```

Then in your controller, you can pass your parameter with no issue

```
public function create($station_id)
```

Comment: I tried this and am getting a different error: `array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

    in Factory.php line 134
    at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array', '/var/www/vnc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php', 134, array('view' => 'newscast.create', 'data' => '4', 'mergeData' => array(), 'path' => '/var/www/vnc/resources/views/newscast/create.blade.php'))`  
  
The create URL is now showing up as **newscast/$station_id** -- isn't this a collision with the actual newscast with the same number (**newscast/9** for example)?