# passing data from controller to blade view laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, laravel-blade

I am trying to send parameters through a href to a page from an events list to an event page.

My route is

```
 Route::get('eventpage', 'EventController@index')->name('eventpage');
```

And my event Controller is

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

   class EventController extends Controller
{

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->query('id');
    $event = DB::table('events')->where('id',$id)->get();
    $pics = DB::table('pictures')->where('event_id',$id)->get();
    $n = count($pics); // the number of pictures for a particular event
    return view('pages.eventPage');
}
```

}

The trouble is that for the first variable I try to use, $n, it gives me an error, "Undefined variable: n "

My blade code is as follows

```
@for($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++)
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{{ $i }}"></li>
@endfor
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there are a lot of questions that explains this, typing your question title will lead you to a tons of similar questions.

Comment: i figured, I just didn't know how to formulate it until I already wrote the question, so I let it be...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data from controller to view in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220482/passing-data-from-controller-to-view-in-laravel)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa my question is so old, I don't even work with laravel anymore haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**route**

```
 Route::get('eventpage', 'EventController@index')->name('eventpage');
```

**event Controller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

   class EventController extends Controller
{

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->query('id');
    $event = DB::table('events')->where('id',$id)->get();
    $pics = DB::table('pictures')->where('event_id',$id)->get();

return view('pages.eventPage',compact('event','pics'));

}

}
```

**blade code**

```
@for($i = 1; $i < count($pics); $i++)
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{{ $i }}"></li>
@endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your data to your view like that:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  ....

  return view('pages.eventPage', compact('id', 'event', 'n'));
}
```