# Pass an specific Variable from the controller to the view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a doubt how to pass the Variable $ info_pago of a controller to be used in the checkout view and how to work on it.
Controller:

```
$info_pago = [
      'merchantId' => "508029",
      'accountId' =>'512321',
      'description' => 'Online Store',
      'referenceCode' => $reference_code,
      'amount' => Cart::total(),
      'signature'=> md5($api_key."~"."508029"."~"."XXXX01"."~". Cart::total() )
  ];

  return view('checkout', ['info_pago' => $info_pago ]);
```

I do not know how to use it for a form in the view, I thought something like this...

```
<input name="merchantId"    type="hidden"  value="{{ $info_pago->merchantId }}" >
          <input name="accountId"     type="hidden"  value="{{ $info_pago->accountId }}" >
          <input name="description"   type="hidden"  value="{{ $info_pago->description }}" >
          <input name="referenceCode" type="hidden"  value="{{ $info_pago->referenceCode}}" >
          <input name="amount"        type="hidden"  value="{{ $info_pago->amount }}"   >
```

I appreciate your suggestions.. TY..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data from controller to view in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220482/passing-data-from-controller-to-view-in-laravel)

Comment: @Richard Camilo Saavedra Coneo: is my answer the accepted answer? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenF, I pass an array having doubts how to use in a view, Like an array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you pass is an array... `$info_pago`

Should you not ask the attributes like an array instead of an object?

So `{{$info_pago['merchantId']}}`

Instead of `{{$info_pago->merchantId}}`

Answer (score 0):

you should use compact instead. so your return would be like this:

return view('checkout', compact('info_pago'));

and use it on your view the same as what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

you can use compact

```
$info_pago = [
  'merchantId' => "508029",
  'accountId' =>'512321',
  'description' => 'Online Store',
  'referenceCode' => $reference_code,
  'amount' => Cart::total(),
  'signature'=> md5($api_key."~"."508029"."~"."XXXX01"."~". Cart::total() )
 ];

 return view('checkout', compact('info_pago'));

in view page
{{$info_page}}
```