# Getting a single value from controller to view in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Following is my controller function for editing a given project:

```
public function edit($id)
    { 
        $project = DB::table("projects")->where('id', $id)->get();
        dd($project);

    }
```

On dumping these values, I get the following array inside a collection:

```
Collection {#360 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#351 ▼
      +"id": 9
      +"createDate": "2017-06-29 12:39:17"
      +"updateDate": null
      +"projectName": "proj"
      +"projectspecs": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I would like to pass the projectName into the view, but when I try passing $project into the view, and try printing the same, it gives me an 'Illegal offset type' error.

```
<input type="text" name="projectName" class="form-control" value="{{$project->projectName}}">
```

I am just trying to print the value of projectName into a textbox, what can be done here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data from controller to view in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220482/passing-data-from-controller-to-view-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
public function edit($id)
    { 
        $project = DB::table("projects")->where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('yourviewfilepath',compact('project'));

    }
```

Comment: It gives me an 'Undefined variable: project' error.

Comment: It's `$project`, not `project`.

Comment: @kerbholz: Please check no need `$` when you use with compact

Comment: @MVS: Glad to help and my answer work for you then please accept my answer

Comment: So what does the compact() do exactly here, I am unable to understand the online references available here?

Comment: @MVS : Please check this [link](https://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/passing-multiple-variables-into-a-laravel-5-view/)

Comment: I am trying to, but I would need 3 more minutes before I can upvote your answer.

Comment: @SaurabhDhariwal Then at least use `'project'`. Thx

Comment: @kerbholz: Yes sorry sir for little mistake

Comment: Ok, so I was tesitng the entire thing, and it turns out not all the values returned through compact are as per the array, and for some it also shows me 'Trying to get property of non-object' error.

Comment: I am sorry, I had to make some changes in my query, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

on your controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{ 
 $project = DB::table("projects")->where('id', $id)->get();
 return view('viewfile',compact('project'));
}
```

on your blade file:

```
<input type="text" name="projectName" class="form-control" value="{{$project[0]->projectName}}">
```

====================================

alternatively, to make it more laravel-like:

```
public function edit($id)
{ 
 $project = Project::find($id);
 return view('viewfile',compact('project'));
}
```

then on your blade file:

```
<input type="text" name="projectName" class="form-control" value="{{$project->projectName}}">
```