# Pass data from controller to View in Laravel

Tags: laravel, view

I have a query that I am not able to pass to the view.

```php
$dias_usados = calendario::where('id_funcionario', '=', $userid)
    ->groupBy('id_funcionario')
    ->sum('contaferias');
```

`dd` outputs the correct expected value.

**I tried to pass to the View as follows**:

```php
return view(
    'ausencia',
    compact('tabela'),
    ['itens' => $ferias],
    ['dias_usados' => $dias_usados]
);
```

I'm having problems with the last one `dias_usados`. The first two work normally.

---

```php
<h3>{{$dias_usados}}</h3>
```

Causes the following error:

> Undefined variable: "dias_usados"

---

I also leave the path I have on the route, but I don't see anything wrong

```
Route::get('Ausencia', [AusenciaController::class, 'index'])->name('ausencia.index');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data from controller to view in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220482/passing-data-from-controller-to-view-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the the definition of the `view` helper

```php
function view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = []) { }
```

You are misusing the function by giving it three separate arrays expecting it to get them as `$data`.

## Fixes

```php
return view('ausencia', [
    'tabela' => $tabela,
    'itens' => $ferias,
    'dias_usados' => $dias_usados,
]);
```

```php
return view('ausencia')
    ->with(compact('tabela'))
    ->with(['itens' => $ferias])
    ->with(['dias_usados' => $dias_usados]);
```

```php
return view(
    'ausencia',
    array_merge(
        compact('tabela'),
        ['itens' => $ferias],
        ['dias_usados' => $dias_usados]
    )
);
```