# Undefined variable $payments laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to print out the lists of payment methods using the `foreach` loop, however, i get an `undefined variable..` error.

Here is my controller class

```
    class HomeController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
        $payments = Payment::where('status', 1)->get();

        return view('user.account.index', [
            'payments' => $payments
        ]);
    }
}
```

and here is my section in my view page(index) i want to loop through

```
@foreach ($payments as $payment)
                  <!-- {{ Cryptocap::getSingleAsset($payment->name) }} -->
                  <div class="card col-md-6 no-padding ">
                      <div class="card-body">
                          <div class="h1 text-muted text-right mb-4">
                              <i class="pe-7s-wallet"></i>
                          </div>

                          <div class="h4 mb-0">
                              <span class="">0.0012930403</span>
                          </div>

                          <small class="text-muted text-uppercase font-weight-bold">BTC</small>
                          <div class="progress progress-xs mt-3 mb-0 bg-flat-color-1" style="width: 40%; height: 5px;"></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
        @endforeach
```

The above approach works on other areas of my application, as this is the approach i have been using throughout the application. But it doesn't seem to work on this particular controller and view.

Comment: In the code you provided it seems there are no errors. Make sure the `$payments` collection isn't empty by dumping it in the view. If it's not empty then maybe these divs are just hidden for some reason? Check them in the generated html.

Comment: Tried it..it doesn't dump...it throws the error again

Comment: Please add the complete error to your question.

Answer (score -2):

Can you give this a try

```
    return View::make("user/regprofile", compact('students')); OR
    return View::make("user/regprofile")->with(array('students'=>$students));
```

For more info visit this link
[Passing data from controller to view in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220482/passing-data-from-controller-to-view-in-laravel)