# How to pass a single value from controller to view Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello i have made a function in my controller that generates random number and i want to pass that result number to the view.

This is the code of the controller:

```
 public function create()
    {
        $randomNumber = random_int(100000, 999999);
        $clients = Client::all();
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('orders/create',compact('clients','products'))
            ->with($randomNumber,(request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
```

I have inserted `->with($randomNumber)` because i saw that people used this method when they had an array and would call it in the view `{{$randomNumber->first}}` but as i mentioned above i have a single value only not an array.

This is the view code:

```
 <input id="orderNumber" type="orderNumber" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="orderNumber" value="{{ $randomNumber }}" required autocomplete="orderNumber">
```

But shows me this error:

**Undefined variable $randomNumber**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data from controller to view in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220482/passing-data-from-controller-to-view-in-laravel)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa no it doesnt because this is the one i saw that i mentioned before i have a single value not an array

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa but the answer is given and approved. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want send a random number to view you can do this :

```
public function create()
    {
        $randomNumber = random_int(100000, 999999);
        $clients = Client::all();
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('orders/create',compact('clients','products'))
            ->with('randomNumber',$randomNumber);
    }
```

Or you want send `(request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5` named by randomNumber

```
->with('randomNumber',(request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
```

Comment: And how do i show it to the view ?

Comment: simply if you can use it in blade like  {{$randomNumber}}

Answer (score 0):

To set variables not necessary in your case.

Everything can be done in a more compact manner, like:

```
return view('orders/create',[
            'clients' => Client::all(),
            'products' => Product::all(),
            'randomNumber' => random_int(100000, 999999),
        ])->with((request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
```

In blade/ view get variable like:

```
{{ $randomNumber }}
```